# getting length of each list within an RDD object

Tags: pyspark, rdd, nested-lists

I have an RDD object like:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[7,2,6,9,10]..]
```

I want to get a list out of it, which is equal to size of the elements within each list:

```
y=[3,4,5..]

Where 3=len([1,2,3], 4=len([4,5,6,7]), 5=len([7,2,6,9,10])...
```

This syntax works in Python:

`[ len(y) for y in yourlist ]`, how to iterate over RDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to perform a `map` operation in your RDD:

```python
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [7,2,6,9,10]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(x)
rdd_length = rdd.map(lambda x: len(x))
rdd_length.collect()
# [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It's taking lot of time for execution, do i need to use sc.parallelize, for RDD?

Comment: @muni `sc.parallelize` is only used to convert non-RDD data (`x` in my example) to RDD, for illustration purposes; if you already have an RDD, you should not use it, and you should start from the `rdd_length` part of my code above...

Comment: So, there are close to 5m records, and each might have some 50-200 elements. Can it be fastened?

Comment: @muni Hard to say (you asked a very specific thing, and the answer was exactly on that), but the dataframe API in Spark may be actually faster for PySpark applications. Check the other answer for performance...

Comment: you could try increasing the number of partitions

Comment: give it a try using the built-in function `size()`, it is meant to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: @TMichel yes, but even when correcting your updated answer, it seems the `map` operation cannot be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dataframe from your RDD and then you can use the `size()` sql function.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([1, 2, 3],),([4,5,6,7],),([7,2,6,9,10],)], ['data'])
df.select(size(df.data)).collect()
#[Row(size(data)=3), Row(size(data)=4), Row(size(data)=5)]
```

### Update

You can create a Dataframe from your original RDD like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

rowrdd = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(data=x))
df = spark.createDataFrame(rowrdd)
...
```

Comment: This will not work if the argument of `createDataFrame` is an RDD, as OP asks

Comment: This takes only the first element of each list! You should change it to `Row(data=x)`...